# How to use the float:left property in CSS without having the trouble I have?

Tags: css, css-float, flowlayout

i'm trying to create a flow layout and i'm having some trouble using float:left property in css.

I have one parent container which has 100% width and 100% height. It contains three containers:
The header, the menu container, and the content container.
The menu is a vertical menu,not a horizontal menu. It comes below the header and then the content container floats left on the menu container.
Now the problem is i want to make it flowlayout. When i reduce the resolution,the floating content container comes below the menu container. I want the content to float with a flowlayout without coming below the menu container.Please provide a solution to this.
Thanks!

Here is the link to the code.

http://jsfiddle.net/VdE7Y/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the width and float from the #content css.

Set the background color of #wrapper to be whatever color you want the background of #content to be.

add `display: inline-block;` to the #content css.

Updated fiddle ----> [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/VdE7Y/2/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `min-width` you have for `#menu-cont`

The layout you are trying to have is very hard to maintain.